# How to fix error 1052 relating to SQL alias

Tags: sql

I received 1052 error code. How can I add an alias to this code below?

```
SELECT consumerid as , count(stars) as starcount
FROM consumer left JOIN review on consumer.consumerid = review.consumerid
group by consumerid
ORDER by reviewcount asc, consumerid asc;
```

Comment: `consumerid as ,` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`consumer_id` is ambiguous in the query since it belongs to both tables. You need to *qualify* it with the identifier of the table it belongs to. It is generally a good practice in SQL to qualify all columns in multi-table queries.

```
select c.consumerid, count(r.stars) as review_count
from consumer c
left join review r on c.consumerid = r.consumerid
group by c.consumerid
order by review_count, c.consumerid;
```